# R Prophet: Issue with Forward Monthly Dates generated using make_future_dataframe function

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I have dataset with ds and y columns. The ds column has last day of each month as shown below:

```
2018-09-30
2018-10-31
2018-11-30
2018-12-31
2019-01-31
2019-02-28
```

When I use to extend the dataframe forward using make_future_dataframe function, I'm getting wrong dates as shown below:

```
2019-05-01
2019-05-31
2019-07-01
2019-07-31
2019-08-31
2019-10-01
```

I'm following this tutorial to create the future dataframe using monthly data: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/non-daily_data.html#monthly-data